# What are those symbols above the racing cars?

Tags: onomatopoeia

In the manga, there are symbols above the cars when they race. In the picture below, it says ガッアアアア in katakana. What does it mean? Is it the sound of drifting or an engine?

[image: Initial D chapter 200]

Answer (score 3):

ガアアアア ("gaaaaa") implies more of an engine sound than the screeching tires I would associate with drifting.

Answer (score 1):

Near as I can tell, it's neither. It rather appears to be the totality of sound emitted by the car travelling at speed, as experienced by an external observer; akin to the sound you would hear as a car travels past you while standing near a road.